# Cache-Control and conditional get

Tags: rest, http, get

I have implemented a REST service and I am using `Last-Modified` to handle conditional get returning `304` when the resource timestamp is not changed.

Does `Cache-Control` value affect when a get/conditional get is executed ?
From some tests I am doing it's not clear.

For example setting `Cache-Control: no-cache` will force a `GET` to be executed and so in my case a conditional get that will download the resource only when it's changed?

`no-cache` will still cache the resource if I am not wrong, it just revalidates it every time.

Does the behaviour change if I use `ETag` instead of `Last-Modified`?

Or this depends on the browser implementation?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Does `Cache-Control` value affect when a get/conditional get is executed ? From some tests I am doing it's not clear.***

Certainly. `Cache-Control` determines how long a resource is fresh. A conditional request only happens after the resource becomes stale.

***For example setting `Cache-Control: no-cache` will force a `GET` to be executed and so in my case a conditional get that will download the resource only when it's changed?***

Right.

***`no-cache` will still cache the resource if I am not wrong, it just revalidates it every time.***

Right.

***Does the behaviour change if I use `ETag` instead of `Last-Modified`?***

No.

Comment: Does a setting like `Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=86400` make sense to indicate to still cache the resource but execute the conditional get every time to see if it was update BUT expire it after the max-age ?

Comment: @res1: No, those directives are incompatible. What do you mean by "expire it"? Expiration in HTTP caching only refers to freshness. Do you mean actually deleting the resource so it's not longer stored and there are no more conditional requests?

Comment: conditional get works because the resource is still stored so I was thinking, as you said, after some time actually delete the resource (the next GET will be a non-conditional GET). Is this possible ? considering the use of `no-cache` too.

Comment: @res1: No, it's not possible. There is a `no-store` directive which prevents storing the resource at all (for security reasons), but there's really no use case for preventing conditional requests after some period of time. Is there a reason you want to do that?

Comment: No particular reason I was trying to have an idea of some doubts about the `Cache-Control` parameters. Just as last question, you mentioned `no-store` but using `no-store` means nothing is stored so conditional get cannot work, right?

Comment: @res1: Right, if you use `no-store` then every request will be a regular non-conditional `GET`.